# Using Atlassian QuickReload with java 7

Tags: jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Developing a JIRA Plugin and would like to use the QuickReload feature. However I am using the 5.0.x SDK and that uses Java 7.  QuickReload appears to need Java 8. Is there a way to get this working for java 7?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used QuickReload with Java 7 on JIRA standalone releases as far back as JIRA 6.1 (without regard to the Plugin SDK version in use).

To get this to work, you can download the [QuickReload sources](https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/quickreload), build it as a JAR with `atlas-mvn package`, and then upload the JAR as a plugin to JIRA. Then add a `quickreload.properties` to the root of your JIRA install directory and everything should work as expected.

(I suppose it's possible that newer versions of quickreload might require a higher version of Java, but this worked fine as of commit a8e25f30fbd.)